# Enabling pre-receive server hook to get PR/MR approval before pushing to dev branch

Tags: gitlab, githooks

Use case: I have code on my local machine and If I try to push it to remote server, a `pre-receive` hook in remote [GitLab] server should get triggered and ask for respective author approval to merge that code onto Gitlab repo.
After [code review] if author approves MR then code from my local repo will be pushed to remote server else push needs to be halted.

I am sure that I was asked to enable `pre-receive` hook on GitLab server side and not on client side.
I think it is not possible because code exists in developer's local machine and hence approver may not be able to do code review but not sure about `pre-receive` working.

Can `pre-receive` hook able to notify approver before code push? If it is possible need to know how?
If not, I want a strong valid point to negotiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MR approval is not requested when one pushed a branch, but only when one makes (once the branch is pushed) a merge request to the target branch.

In your case:

- [protect the `dev` branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html) (nobody can push directly to it, so no need for a pre-receive hook)
- make a [merge request mandatory for that branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/protected_branches.html#require-everyone-to-submit-merge-requests-for-a-protected-branch)
- make sure to [configure your merge requests so that they must be approved before they can be merged.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/approvals/)

That means any code eventually merged to `dev`:

- will *not* have been pushed directly to `dev` (MR required)
- will have been reviewed and approved first, before being accepted and merged to `dev`.

While it is true *enforcing* the MR approval process, meaning disabling the "Merge" button as long as approval is not met, is **not free** (premium only), you still have a way to enforce it.

Make sure nobody can push/merge to `dev` is a "Merge Manager" who is alone responsible to merge or not the MRs. If said merge manager sees there is no approval, they won't merge the MR.

Comment: Can I do it for PR then? I was asked to avoid unreviewed code get pushed onto GitLab dev branch from developers local machine. When he/she tries to push something, it should first notify the approver and then next actions has to be happened. Does post-commit hook has anything  to do with this? I am not even sure about it

Comment: @Vasantha If the dev branch is protected, no code (reviewed or not) can be pushed. You need to make a MR, and You can configure your merge requests so that they must be approved before they can be merged. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I got your point, but as per the doc "GitLab Free are optional, and don’t prevent a merge request from merging without approval". So, I afraid above steps might not work for Gitlab-ce.

Comment: @Vasantha It can work in GitLab-CE: since only a merge manager can merge anything to dev (and nobody else can push to dev), said merge manager simply won't accept/merge MR without approval. It is less convenient than an automatic check which would disable the merge button, but it is *still* a way to enforce the approval process.